# Fortigate 310B... internal tunnelled clients can not access interal hosted sites

Tags: firewall, nat, fortinet

I have a new Fortinet firewall (310B)

Internal IP is `172.16.1.7`
External IP #1 is `164.58.180.210` (secondary `211-222`)
External IP #2 is `164.58.12.30`

Internal IP is the default gateway.  External is our primary internet connection and used to host our website, blog, and mail site.  External-VIPs are setup so that connections coming into `mail.tahlequah.k12.ok.us` resolve to `164.58.180.214`, come in on the external 1 interface and translate to `172.16.1.8` and respond *(works as intended)*.

Internal Clients have internal DNS configured so that they resolve directly to `172.16.1.8` and respond *(works as intended)*.

**The problem** is I have an MSM controller on our network at `172.16.0.10` that tunnels wireless clients *(guest internet)*.  They all get addresses of `192.168.x.x` and are unable to access any internal IP addresses.  They go out to the internet throught the External Interface #2 (`164.58.12.30`) and have external DNS configured.

They resolve to `164.58.180.214` also but of course the fortinet does not respond.

Is there a way to get the Fortinet to answer these requests and send it inside the network to `172.16.1.8` like external clients do?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell by just looking at your post and not the actual device itself but it sounds a little bit like you have a NATed policy from [192 client interface] > WAN but are missing a NATed policy from [192 client interface] to INTERNAL.